# Why can't I Switch Batsuit?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I finished the game and I have downloaded all of the bat suits. But it doesn’t give me the option to change suits.

Comment: What happens when you try to switch?

Answer (score 1):

When you go to resume your saved game you should automatically be given option to choose your batsuit.Considering you have unlocked alternate batsuits,and game is not bugged.

You can see below how it should look.You can ignore the starting of the video since it is just a cheatcode for unlocking the batsuits.